# Сжатие JS файлов в Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

Необходимо, чтобы Gulp следил за файлами в папке `dist/js`  и при изменении любого из них, сжимал его и складывал в эту же папку с суффиксом `.min`.

`task "js"` у меня в `gulpfile.js` выглядит так:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src(['js/*.js', '!js/*.min.js']) // Исключаем минифицированные файлы
        .pipe(uglify()) // Сжимаем JS файл
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'})) // Добавляем суффикс .min
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/)); // Выгружаем в папку назначения
 });


gulp.task('watch', ['js'], function() {
    gulp.watch(['js/*.js', '!js/signup/*.min.js'], ['js']);
});
```

Таск работает, если в папке только один файл, если же их несколько, он находит только первый подходящий под условие, обрабатывает его и останавливается.

Вопрос: как обработать все файлы?

Файловая структура такая: 5 файлов `.js`, 5 файлов `.min.js` + 1 `.php`, после внесения правки (из ответа Nikita Smith) опять таки обрабатывается первый файл `.js` в списке, остальные без изменений.

Comment: Может быть надо сначала сделать rename, а потом uglify или может быть забыли `return` перед `gulp.src`.

Comment: Нет ) таск ведь работает корректно, только с одним файлом )

Answer (score 1):

Обычно использую так, все работает, ***пример:***

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var pump = require('pump');

gulp.task('js', function (cb) {
  pump([
        gulp.src(['js/*.js', '!js/*.min.js']),
        uglify(),
        rename({suffix: '.min'}),
        gulp.dest('js/')
    ],
    cb
  );
});
```

ps. Заметьте, вместо `pipe` используется `pump`.

Лучше использовать разные папки для исходников `app` для всего исходного кода до "вмешательства" `gulp`, а `dist` после. Так у вас пути не потеряются, и обжатый продукт можно так же без проблем запустить.

Comment: К сожалению результата нет..