# Минификация js + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, минификация

У меня есть самописная либа на `js` + `jQuery`. Хочу ее минифицировать, но не могу понять как. Может кто подсказать инструменты для такой штуки. В данный момент нашел инструменты только для `js` (`jQuery` он не понимает). На нативный `js` не очень хотелось бы переписывать.

Comment: https://javascript-minifier.com/ или  https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561125/%D0%A1%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-js-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-gulp